# The relation between U(1) charge conservation and electronic insulator

Tags: conservation-laws, topological-insulators

I am now learning the topological classification and have some problems on the paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1843) I am reading now.

In this paper, there is a statement in the second part ( II. REFLECTION SYMMETRY IN BAND INSULATORS ) :

*We focus on electronic insulators, i.e., systems with a conserved U(1) charge, but a similar tight-binding formalism can be developed for BdG Hamiltonians of topological superconductors, since both kinds of Hamiltonians can be treated as noninteracting systems.*

The part I don't understand is the relation between **electronic insulators** and **conserved U(1) charge**

To the best of my knowledge, the U(1) charge conservation means that if we make the following transformation :

$\psi^{\dagger} \left( {\bf r} \right) \to e^{i\theta}\psi^{\dagger} \left( {\bf r} \right)$

$\psi \left( {\bf r} \right) \to e^{-i\theta}\psi \left( {\bf r} \right)$

then the Hamiltonian $H$ won't change. This means that the particle number of the system will conserve since it can be shown that $\left[ {H,N} \right] = 0$ where $N$ is the number operator defined by $N = \int {d{\bf{r}}{\psi ^\dagger }\left( {\bf{r}} \right){\psi ^{}}\left( {\bf{r}} \right)} $

However, I don't know why this property has some relation with the **electronic insulator**

Is there any suggested reference for me to explore this topic more? I would be extremely grateful for any suggestion!!

Thanks!

Comment: Your formulas refer to the U(1) symmetry, not charge. I haven't read the paper, but I suspect that the authors might mean the conditions where charges don't cross the boundaries of an object thus making this object non-conductive.

Comment: @safesphere Thanks for your reply. Can you explain more about the difference between U(1) symmetry and U(1) charge? I tried to find some relevant lecture notes but failed. Can you suggest some reference that I can read more about U(1) ? Thanks!

Comment: I'll leave the details to the experts, but essentially U(1) means that "circles are round" and when you put it on top of the Lorentz invariance of Special Relativity ("local gauge"), you get electromagnetism both classical and quantum. So the U(1) symmetry is never broken, as it is the foundation of this universe. As stated in comments below, it may be convenient for calculations to consider it broken instead of accounting for complex boundary conditions. I already have guessed what the authors may have meant by the"U(1) charge", but I'll leave the full answer to the experts.

Answer (score 1):

The authors want to distinguish between types of gapped systems. An ordinary insulator with an ordinary gap, and a superconductor which has a gap but with broken U(1) symmetry. In fact, metals also respect U(1) symmetry, though this may or may not hold in the strongly interacting case.

Comment: The U(1) symmetry is never broken. The question is about the U(1) charge, not symmetry.

Comment: For the true microscopic Hamiltonian, yes U(1) is never broken. However, the effective BCS Hamiltonian for superconductors does break this symmetry. This gives rise to the Higgs mode as pointed out by Phil Anderson many decades ago. So my answer still stands.

Comment: I would like to emphasize that most, if not all, studies of topology in solid state systems these days are done on effective Hamiltonians (tight binding etc.) So breaking of U(1) symmetry is a very useful way to understand things,  even though it not true strictly speaking.

Comment: @user157879 Thanks for the reply. Can you illustrate more about the relation between gap system and the U(1) symmetry/charge ?
Since I am novice for this research field, I would like to explore more about U(1) charge/symmetry, can you further suggest some reference ?
Thanks!

Comment: U(1) symmetry basically means charge is conserved (number of electrons does not change). This is the general interpretation you would get from  quantum field theory. For models of ordinary insulators or simple metals, charge is still conserved. This has nothing to do with gapped or not gapped. For the BCS model of superconductors, charge is no longer conserved, so U(1) symmetry is broken. Microscopically, U(1) symmetry is always conserved,  but the BCS model and tight binding models are not microscopically correct, so U(1) can be broken.

Comment: @user157879 Do you mean that the author considers 2 kinds of gapped systems, one is electronic insulator which preserves U(1) symmetry, and the other is superconductor which breaks U(1) symmetry although it still has a gap?
And the reason why superconductor breaks the U(1) symmetry is inherent in the BCS description because BCS description does not preserve the particle number.
Is my understanding correct?
Thanks!

Comment: @Kuan-Sen Lin Yes I would say that's correct.